# Sqlalchemy class _MatchType(sqltypes.Float, sqltypes.MatchType): AttributeError

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**sometimes execute query and got this error:**

```
ct = db.session.query(CIType).filter(
                CIType.type_name == key).first() or \
                db.session.query(CIType).filter(CIType.type_id == key).first()
```

**full error info**

```
2016-08-11 14:27:26,177 ERROR /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py 1306 - Exception on /api/v0.1/projects/search-indexer-rafael/product [GET]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/data/webapps/cmdb-api/core/special.py", line 175, in get_project_product
    product = ProjectManager().get_for_product(project_name)
File "/data/webapps/cmdb-api/lib/special/project.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.ci_type = CITypeCache.get("project")
File "/data/webapps/cmdb-api/models/cmdb.py", line 458, in get
    ct = db.session.query(CIType).filter(
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 149, in do
    def do(self, *args, **kwargs):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 903, in __call__
    item = dict.get(self, key)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy.py", line 201, in __init__
    bind=db.engine,
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy.py", line 754, in engine
    return self.get_engine(self.get_app())
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy.py", line 771, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy.py", line 451, in get_engine
    self._engine = rv = sqlalchemy.create_engine(info, **options)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 344, in create_engine
    of 0 indicates no limit; to disable pooling, set ``poolclass`` to
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 50, in create

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 116, in get_dialect
    return self.get_dialect().driver
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 170, in load
    fn.__func__.__doc__ = doc
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/__init__.py", line 33, in _auto_fn
    try:
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import base, mysqldb, oursql, \
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 681, in <module>
    class _MatchType(sqltypes.Float, sqltypes.MatchType):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MatchType'
```

**code**

```
@special.route("/api/v0.1/projects/<string:project_name>/product",
           methods=["GET"])
def get_project_product(project_name):
    product = ProjectManager().get_for_product(project_name)
    return jsonify(product=product)
...
```

goto

```
class ProjectManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ci_type = CITypeCache.get("project")
...
```

then

```
class CITypeCache(object):
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, key):
        if key is None:
            return
        ct = cache.get("CIType::ID::%s" % key) or \
            cache.get("CIType::Name::%s" % key)
        if ct is None:
            ct = db.session.query(CIType).filter(
                CIType.type_name == key).first() or \
                db.session.query(CIType).filter(CIType.type_id == key).first()
            if ct is not None:
                CITypeCache.set(ct)
        return ct
```

The sqlalchemy's version is **SQLAlchemy-1.0.8-py2.6.egg-info**

and after many same error, I can't catch this error any more. What's the reason of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I assume CIType.type_name and CIType.type_id have different data types (perhaps string and numeric types). It may lead to situation when:

```
db.session.query(CIType).filter(CIType.type_name == key).first()
```

is valid expression but:

```
db.session.query(CIType).filter(CIType.type_id == key).first()
```

produces error because of type mismatch. You need to convert key to the type_id column type in this expression.

The second expression is calculated when first expression returns no results. As written in [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

For example:

```
>>> a = 1 or 2 + '2'
>>> print a
1
>>> a = 0 or 2 + '2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Sorry I did not give all the info before and Now I give the code and all call stack. So may not be the situation you describe.

Comment: @SkyWay Could you post CIType definition as well?

Comment: as you assume: actually `type_name` is string and `type_id` is integer. But the function call as `CITypeCache.get("project")`, this situation it will execute statement `db.session.query(CIType).filter(CIType.type_name == key).first()`. Besides, there is no float type.

Comment: @SkyWay `or` keyword in expressions works different way: _sometimes_ `db.session.query(CIType).filter(CIType.type_id == key).first()` is also calculated and can cause this error. I added more explanations in my answer. [MatchType](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.MatchType) is something different: it is the type of result of comparison which is float in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, I know the situation you said is possible. But now I test `db.session.query(CIType).filter(CIType.type_name == key).first()` and `db.session.query(CIType).filter(CIType.type_id == key).first()` in the same time when key is string and integer, and have not occured any error .

Comment: @SkyWay My only guess now is that it is or was some installation error: MatchType class was added in SQLAlchemy 1.0.0. Perhaps SQLAlchemy was firstly installed via yum or apt-get and then flask_sqlalchemy and its dependencies were installed via pip. It could lead to several versions of the package installed (e.g. in /usr/lib64/ and /usr/lib/).

Comment: It's strange. I did not find different version package in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64`.  flask-sqlalchemy is `Flask_SQLAlchemy-0.16-py2.6.egg-info`